# What do the symbols in the "travel to battlefield" screen mean?

Tags: wu-long-fallen-dynasty

When traveling to a battlefield, there are empty spaces, presumably for items that can be collected.

[image: Wu long picture]

What do these represent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Golden Chicada image] **Golden Chicada**
You give these to the guy in the village, and he gives you armor/weapons in return.

[image: Tablet image] **Tablet**
These tell a bit of the story. Aside from that they're only needed for an achievement.

[image: Dragon Vein Essence image] **Dragon Vein Essence**
These increase how effective potions are.

[image: Dragon Vein Crystal image] **Dragon Vein Crystal**
These increase how many potions you can hold.

[image: Panda image] **Panda**
If you drop an item near one, it will turn it into a different item of the same rarity.